# How to extract certain words from a "disassembled" file

Tags: regex, perl

I'm doing exactly this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env/perl

open FILE1, "<Exed.exe";
open FILE2, ">Fileinhexadecimal.txt";

binmode FILE1;

while (<FILE1>) {
$lines = $_;
$lines = unpack("H*", $lines);
chomp $lines;
print FILE2 "$lines\n";
}

close (FILE1);
close (FILE2)
print "Finish\n";
<>;
```

After, i created other program to read this ".txt" file to search some infos.

With this script, I'm creating a text file containing hexadecimal data of a .exe file.
My great problem is :

1- I want extract the line with regexp : `/8B55-(.*)-8B55/` (With the second script, that wasn't posted here)

2 - Here is the problem :

Ever my file.txt is like this :

```
8B55-646464-8B558B55-636363-8B55
8B55-656565-8B558B55-666666-8B55
```

When i run the script, the script just pop these data :

```
"646464", "656565".
```

You still not understanding my question.
I want to extract : `646464, 636363, 656565, 666666`. But the script, when it found the first match, he's jumping to the next line, don't reading the rest.

Can you help how could i catch all matchs ?
Other example :

```
8B55-646464-8B55987941651968798779878B55-686868-8B55
8B55-ILOVEYOU-8B55
```

Here, the script will only catch the `646464` and `ILOVEYOU`. (is missing 686868):/

The real file that i'm searching for some data, is very big and have some lines, bigger than this example.

I tried to use "g" : if ($lines =~ /(.*)/g) {

but not works.

My second script :

I'm trying running this script :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


open FILE, "<Fileinhexadecimal.txt";

while (<FILE>) {
$lines = $_;
if ($lines =~ /8B55-(.*)-8B55/g) {
print "-$1\n";
}
}
close (FILE)

<>;
```

And nothing happens. I'm trying extract certain sequencial words from a giant file, and is happening this, i just used 8B55 as example. But the problem is the same. New idea ? How could i use your code ?

@match = /8B55-(.*?)-8B55/g;
print "@match\n";

??? thanks for resp and sorry for the bad english

Real question

The line is :

8BCEE84EC4FFFF6A016A2B6A2B686C0100008BCEE83CC4FFFF6A016A2B6A2B686C0100008BCEE82AC4FFFF6A016A0E6A0E686D0100008BCEE818C4FFFF6A016A146A1468F20100008BCEE806C4FFFF6A006A0E6A0E68700100008BCEE8F4C3FFFF6A016A1E6A1E6871010000

In this line, i have 6 data to extract.

I use this regexp to extract :

8BCEE8....FFFF6A(..)6A(..)6A(..)68(..)(..)0000

On the first line, we have 3 matchs, on the second we have 2 matchs and last line we have 1 match (8BCEE8F4C3FFFF6A016A1E6A1E6871010000)

I want to extract, practically, \1 \2 \3 \4 and \5. I tried using if :

if ($lines =~ /8BCEE8....FFFF6A(..)6A(..)6A(..)68(..)(..)0000/g) {
print "$5$4 $1$2$3"
}

But with this code, i just can take one match per line. And not all matchs. Understood ? :/
I want to extract, by example, here :

8BCEE84EC4FFFF6A016A2B6A2B686C010000

I want to extract the word after 6A, after 6A, after 6A and the 4 letters after 68. :/ \o/ thanks for the advise, iluv u!

In this file, there are 1000 lines with the same regexp. I want to extract these 1000 lines.

Comment: Please show the code that you're having problems with, not some other code that produces the data.

Comment: I edited my first post with the script code, to catch those infos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
while (<DATA>) {
  print $1, "\n" while /(?<=8B55-)(\w+)(?=-8B55)/g;
}

__DATA__
8B55-646464-8B558B55-636363-8B55
8B55-656565-8B558B55-666666-8B55
8B55-646464-8B55987941651968798779878B55-686868-8B55
8B55-ILOVEYOU-8B55
```

**output**

```
646464
636363
656565
666666
646464
686868
ILOVEYOU
```

---

**Update**

This does what I think you need for your full question.

```
while (<DATA>) {

  while (/8BCEE8....FFFF6A(..)6A(..)6A(..)68(..)(..)0000/g) {
    print join(' ', $1, $2, $3, $4, $5), "\n";
  }
}

__DATA__
8BCEE84EC4FFFF6A016A2B6A2B686C0100008BCEE83CC4FFFF6A016A2B6A2B686C0100008BCEE82AC4FFFF6A016A0E6A0E686D0100008BCEE818C4FFFF6A016A146A1468F20100008BCEE806C4FFFF6A006A0E6A0E68700100008BCEE8F4C3FFFF6A016A1E6A1E6871010000
```

**output**

```
01 2B 2B 6C 01
01 2B 2B 6C 01
01 0E 0E 6D 01
01 14 14 F2 01
00 0E 0E 70 01
01 1E 1E 71 01
```

Comment: Yeah,it's helped me so much. It's what i was searching all time.
But my really trouble is more complicated, because don't have - to separate the words.

Look :

8BCEE8(..)C5FFFF6A(..)6A(..)6A(..)68(..)(..)0000

I'm trying just to get ALL between (), but i can't get it.

How could i get the \2 \3 \4 and \5 using your code ? and how to print in a file ? sorry, i'm very newbie. =/

Comment: Please add to your question and show a sample of your real data.

Comment: I edited with a real data. Still a little confused, but i think you will understand. thanks for the advise *-*

Comment: OMG. Stickied!  Thanks so much, you are the angel of my life. hehe! thanks so much so much ! stay with God. *-*